# I am unable to obtain to obtain the href element from the data I have pulled, how can I select it?

Tags: axios

I am unable to obtain to obtain the href element from the data I have pulled, I have had no problem getting the rest of the data. I keep getting errors like "link is not defined" or "href is not defined".

```
function Data() {
  const [Music, setMusic] = useState([], {});
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json")
      .then((data) => {
        setMusic(data.data.feed.entry);
     })  
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  const filtered = Music.length
    ? Music.filter(
        (music) =>
          music["im:name"]["label"].toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
          music["im:artist"]["label"].toLowerCase().includes(search)
      )
    : [];

 
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav onChange={handleSearch} placeHolder={"search title, artist"} />
      <article id="article" className="albums">
        <ul className="album-items">
          {filtered.map((Music) => {
            const { id } = Music;
            return (
              <div key={id.attributes["im:id"]} className="album"><a href='{Music["href"]}'></a>
                <li className="album-list" key={id.attributes["im:id"]}>
                    <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart" a href='{Music["href"]}'></i>
                  <SimplePopover Music={Music}>
                    <img
                      src={Music["im:image"][2].label}
                      alt={Music["im:name"].label}
                    />
                  </SimplePopover>
                </li>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what the structure of the items in Music is?

Comment: I have already answered it myself. If you are interested I can add it for you.

Comment: If you have an answer, please [add it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, I had been targeting the wrong link.

Correct method:

```
<a  href={Music["id"].label}></a>
```

Incorrect:

```
<a href='{Music["href"].label}'></a>
```